# Increasing cron script duration in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, cron

I have module, that needs some time to execute, but instead cron gives me blank page(i dont know what exactly, but i think its timed out). How can i increase duration of cron execution in drupal 7?

Comment: You have to go to your php and server settings to increase the max_execution_time. Also, check your error logs to make sure that it's not exiting the script due to an error. Finally, for the time-being set up your cron manager to send you an email each time a job completes.

Comment: Somehow my script managed to complete without increasing time. But it happened only once, an i didnt do anything to force script execution.

Comment: If you are seeing a blank page when accessing cron.php?key=dsadsada page, you will receive a blank page which is correct.You can confirm this by checking last cron timestamp.